# What are the main World of Warcraft books?

Tags: history, folklore, warcraft

I have been playing WoW for years now, and I enjoy the history and story lines within the game, but find it difficult to really follow all the various character developments and motivations.  Is there a 'definitive' set of books that I could read to follow the story?  If so, which?  I'm not referring to fan fiction or webisodes or comics.

Primarily, at least, the plots associated with the game directly, but also all the prior lore, like the initial imprisoning of Deathwing, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO, if you just want the essential details, my recommendation would be to read the wiki pages concerning the topics you want to know more about. You would get the same essential details by reading for a few minutes vs spending hours reading a book.

http://www.wowwiki.com/Deathwing

If you're interested in reading novels, these resources might help

http://www.wowwiki.com/Story_guide

http://www.wowwiki.com/Novels

Comment: Thanks.  I don't mind reading novels, and I want to get to 'know' the characters better.  Trying to follow everything while playing is nigh impossible.  There are quite a few more books than I thought; the lists are great.

Answer (score 4):

The fantasy novel [Jaina Proudmoore: Tides of war](http://www.wowwiki.com/Jaina_Proudmoore%3a_Tides_of_War) by [Christie Golden](http://www.christiegolden.com/) covers in detail the events leading up to, during and following the destruction of [Theramore](http://www.wowwiki.com/Theramore_Isle), an event which occurs directly in the game in the [Theramore's Fall](http://wowpedia.org/Theramore%27s_Fall) scenario.

The novel also covers the interactions between various horde leaders with [Garosh](http://wowpedia.org/Garrosh_Hellscream) as he attacks theramore and lays a foundation for the unfolding drama that culminates with the [Siege of Orgrimmar](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/blog/10702332/Preparing_for_Patch_54_Siege_of_Orgrimmar-21_08_2013)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna know how it all started read Rise of the Horde. This is about how it all happend and where the demons come from and where the Dreanei come from

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site.  Generally answers are encouraged to summarize the answer from the referenced resource.